# Retain specific columns in a Table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Alter table tablename
drop column c1,c2,c3,c4;
```

I have an idea of doing in above way!

is there any other way to alter table by just keeping wanted columns instead of dropping unwanted columns

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
create or replace table tablename
select c5, c6, c7
from tablename;
```

I should point out that dropping columns in the manner you are using will be a very fast operation, but the underlying micro-partitions will not be rewritten, so you will not gain the performance that you will be rebuilding the table as I'm suggesting.

The other consideration is that when you recreate the table in this manner, you lose time-travel information.